# Matrix of Columns, I want just a regular matrix!

Tags: list-manipulation

I've been at this problem for a couple of hours now and no success. I'm very new to *Mathematica* I hope someone can help. I have the following

```
 matrix = 
   {{{{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, 
     {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, 
     {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}}, 
    {{{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {1/Sqrt[6]}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, 
     {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, 
     {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}}, 
    {{{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {1/Sqrt[3]}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, 
     {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, 
     {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}}, 
    {{{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {1/Sqrt[2]}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, 
     {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, 
     {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}}};
```

mut what I want is just `{{0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0}, ...` and so on for 48 rows. I'm pretty sure I need to do some funky `Flatten`, but how?

Comment: You should try with `ArrayFlatten` maybe. See: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html

Comment: Array flatten also does nothing.....

Comment: `Partition[Flatten[matrix], 6]`?

Comment: Stelios you are an absolute legend, and anyone that disagrees, we'll get them to pm me and I'll persuade them otherwise. Thank you!

Comment: @user35529 LOL, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further reflection,

```
Flatten[Flatten[yourmatrix, {3, 4}], 1]
```

I missed the extra higher level of structure. The inner `Flatten` gets the low level, the outer the high level.

Comment: Didn't seem to do anything.....

Comment: Worked for me in 10.1 on Mac

Comment: Actually I got a 8 by 6 matrix, all zeroes....

Comment: I appreciate the effort, stelios's suggestion above worked. Thanks. :)

Comment: @user35529 it can also be done in a single `Flatten` call: `Flatten[matrix, {{2, 1}, {3, 4}}]`. Actually, with more non-zero elements in the matrix, you will see that this yields the correct result, whereas the code of this answer does not.

Comment: At least, I think so. It is not really very clear which levels you want flattened together. An example of your expected output would make it unambiguous and so greatly improve the question.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
 data = 
   {{{{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, 
     {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, 
     {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}}, 
    {{{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {1/Sqrt[6]}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, 
     {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, 
     {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}}, 
    {{{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {1/Sqrt[3]}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, 
     {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, 
     {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}}, 
    {{{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {1/Sqrt[2]}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, 
     {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, 
     {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}}};

Flatten[Map[Flatten, data, {2, -2}], 1]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/Sqrt[6], 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/Sqrt[3], 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/Sqrt[  2], 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
> ```

Comment: This is equivalent to `Flatten[matrix, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]`. But as I mentioned on the accepted answer, there are many ways to flatten the four levels together and it is hard to tell what result OP actually expects, especially when the majority of the elements are zeros.

Answer (score 3):

as I understand you have at the top level a 6x8 matrix which really represents 48 rows, flatten the top level first then flatten each row:

```
   Flatten /@ Flatten[matrix, 1]
```

or ..

```
   First@*Transpose /@ Flatten[matrix, 1]
```

This is essentially the reverse order of operations as JohnD's method, a matter of what you find more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another

```
Join @@ Map[Flatten, matrix, {2}]
```